# jScrollpane misbehavior after several trigger

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I am using jscrollpane http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ in my site and it working, but not 100%.

To be clear, I am using the jscrollpane on a list of images to cater for the horizontal overflow. The images is located inside a div, and I will change the div content once user click on different buttons. Thus, I need to set the maintainPosition to false to ensure after the div content is change, it is not being "over-scroll" to the right and making contents at the left invisible.

Here is my code:

```
// function to change the div content
function getContainerImg(cid) {

// Use jscrollpane api function to enable reinitialization
    var scrollelement = $('#containersimg').jScrollPane({ maintainPosition: false });
    var api = scrollelement.data('jsp');
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '@(Url.Action("GetContainersImg", "Kitchen"))',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { name: cid },
        success: function (result) {

            api.getContentPane().html(result);
            // Needed to apply jscrollpane after change new container type
            api.reinitialise();

            $('#containersimg').effect('slide', 500);
```

I had tested several scenario during testing, there are some weird behavior occur:

1. If i open my site and let it idle for a while, the maintainPosition is failed to work, making the updated images not visible
2. If i click on the button to switch the content several times, the scroll bar will disappear some time, it will only re-appear if i trigger the content change again

EDIT:
Include an image to illustrate my situation:
[image]

EDIT 2:
Include full code here:

pastebin.com/qfVSp2tq
Css:

pastebin.com/FdMXhS5B

The missing of scrollbar is occured more and more frequent...

Any idea why is this problem occur? It is very important bug since user might not be able to see the content if the scroll bar retain its position to the right-most or when the scroll bar is not appear at all.

I am thinking possible reason might be the order i construct the scroll bar. Any advise??
Thank you very much...

Comment: If you haven't already, try setting the width of each image to make sure that jScrollpane allocates the correct total width, such as: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image2.html.

Comment: HI, thanks, but each image is already having a fixed width..

Comment: How about calling `scrollToX(0)`? I would be able to help more efficiently if you could provide the site or at least relevant HTML/CSS. You say your ajax function works just fine, and I can't find anything wrong in the jScrollPane call.

Comment: Hi, there are 2 main problems here, the maintainPosition problem is occur less frequently than the missing of scroll bar ( problem 2 in my question ). I wonder why after several change of the div content, the scrollbar is missing...

Comment: Visually, I can't spot anything wrong. If you added the full code, I could debug it much more effectively with tools.

Comment: perhaps i can give u more details at chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5748/jscrollpane
Thanks...

Comment: Those pastes are invalid (broken links).  This is exactly why we frown on pastebins on SO.  If it is too much code, you haven't distilled your problem enough.

Comment: Hi, please refer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/G228Z/2/
Thanks!

Comment: I modified your code to have a working demo with dummy images http://jsfiddle.net/WGRqF/. Could you please try to reproduce the behavior and post the updated sample plus the reproducing steps.

Answer (score 0):

i have one confusion ,may be it helps you,see when you click image is slide down 500,but on ajax request is there any content is received?,may empty content override your last 3 images,and because empty content received you see nothing,i am not sure but may it be..